# branch.io +is_first_session is giving random values every time I delete and reinstall the app

Tags: branch.io

+is_first_session is giving random values every time I delete and reinstall the app. I tried doing this more than 20 times.

I have submitted 2 tickets in this regard.

Comment: Questions that need tech support assistance are not on-topic here, since readers are not able to view restricted information about your account, nor access the systems required to fix it. If you can amend your question such that any reader might be able to help then please do so - I doubt the above detail is currently sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out! More information about your issue will be needed. Please submit a ticket to the Branch Support team at support@branch.io and we will be happy to investigate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have submitted 2 tickets. Please check this is urgent.